# Matrix partwise multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on an artificial intelligence application that (among other things) combines "opinions" of several "experts" who each have access to different aspects of a "situation". I can build this application in a powerful new way, if there is a general solution to this problem in linear algebra.

Given a matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and vectors $A\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^n$ where:

$M_{i,j}\geq 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$

$\sum _{j=1}^n M_{i,j}=A_i$

$\sum _{i=1}^m M_{i,j}=B_j$

(in vector form: $J_m.M=A$ and $M.J_n=B$ )

Describe all matrices $F\in \mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

$F_{i,j}\geq 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq m$ and $1\leq j\leq n$

$\sum _{j=1}^n F_{i,j} M_{i,j}=A_i$

$\sum _{i=1}^m F_{i,j} M_{i,j}=B_j$

(in vector form: $J_m.(F * M)=A$ and $(F * M).J_n=B$ )

(another matrix form: 
$F.M^{\mathsf{T}}* \mathbb{I}_m=diag(u)$ and 
$F^{\mathsf{T}}.M* \mathbb{I}_n=diag(v)$)

Please note that I am looking for a description of ALL the matrices, thus I expect the solution to have (*m*-1)(*n*-1) parameters (I'm guessing -- please check if this is the correct number of parameters), and I'm also going to need the constraints on these parameters.

I'm hoping there is an elegant solution here, based on orthogonalization or something similar. I need this for an AI application and I am not a mathematician, thus a specific formula or algorithm would be preferred.

Finally, is there a name for this problem? Or for the matrices and vectors involved? If matrices with these descriptions have names, please edit the title of this question to reflect that. If the name of the algorithm (or the class of algorithms) is known, then the name alone would constitute an answer to the question.

Trivial solution that won't work:
There are many easy ways to describe the space of matrices G such that 
$\sum _{j=1}^n G_{i,j}=A_i$ and $\sum _{i=1}^m G_{i,j}=B_j$. You might be inclined to think that the answer to this question is simply to let $F_{i,j} = G_{i,j}/M_{i,j}$, and provide a description of G. This can't work, however, because it is possible that $M_{i,j} = 0$. If there is a zero, then means that F will have to increase the  elements in row i and column j, and correspondingly decrease the elements outside that row and column, but as they decrease, they may not go below zero. This is the issue that makes the problem hard.

Some hints: 
The dot product of the rows of F with rows of M is a constant, therefor each row of M is a vector at a constant angle from the vector made from a row of F. The same is true of the columns. F must satisfy both.

Comment: I don't think there's going to a be a particularly useful characterization of the solution space. Note that your sum-product doesn't correspond to any matrix operation I'm familiar with - neither matrix product, nor outer product, nor Kronecker Product (some similarlity there). For any fixed $M_{i, j}$, you can find an $F_{i, j}$ to make their product $A_i$; and arguing similarly, use two other row entries to make them equal in absolute value, but of opposite sign - you get typically an infinite solution space. That said, maybe it's a matrix operation I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Yes, it's an infinite space -- (m-1)(n-1) parameters in the general case, less for some values of M. The suggestion you made is good, but it leads to a trivial solution that I know won't work. I added this to the problem above.

Comment: Also, note that this problem arose in the context of statistical reasoning for artificial intelligence, rather than physics, so the matrix operations that are appropriate to physics are not as useful here.